# InvalidAuthenticityToken for disabled cookies on smart phones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, protect-from-forgery

Using Rails 3.0.3 and Heroku

I get errors like InvalidAuthenticityToken for form posts on my Heroku app. In my application controller I have protect_from_forgery enabled.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  ...
end
```

my search form

```
<%= form_tag(searchresults_url) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search_query, '', :size => 14 %> <%= submit_tag (t :search) %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
match 'searchresults' => 'home#searchresults', :as  => :searchresults

class HomeController < ApplicationController


  def searchresults

    @query = query_string
        @entries_found = Counter.where(...)     

  end


end
```

The invalid toke error occurs when someone tries to search the website through my search form and when they  have **cookies disabled** and using a smart phone. I have tried to access the website with my web browser (Firefox) with cookies disabled and it worked fine.

I do not get this behavior on "search engines" I have created (in ways I cannot use in this app) so what is wrong. Why just smart phones and cookies disabled?

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty "solution" to this was to add

```
protect_from_forgery :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]
```

for the related controllers. I am not sure though what risk this poses to the website...